# ActionScript 3.0: Class Relationships

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript

Im having trouble understanding class relationships after being asked to research it further, would anyone be able to help?

If I were to create 'Class A', and Class A has all the attributes and methods we need for a new class C, but class C requires at least 3 new methods and 3 new attributes, is it possible to form a relationship between Class A and C, and if so, what kind of relationship would that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of class inheritance like the following.

You have a Class Automobile. It has a motor, a frame, a fuel tank, wheels.

From there you can inherit/extend Automobile class to create a Racing Car.

Racing Car has a motor, a frame, fuel tank, wheels, but it also has air conditioning and a radio.

Another example would be a bulldozer, it has a motor, a frame, a fuel tank, wheels, no air conditioning but it has a Shovel in front of it etc...

Answer (score 3):

This is called [**inheritance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29).

- `C` inherits from `A`.
- `C` is a subclass (or child class) of `A`.
- `A` is the superclass (or parent class) of `C`.

This can be achieved like the following in as3:

```
public class C extends A
{
    public function C()
    {
        super(); // The constructor of class A
    }

    public function methodC1()
    {

    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class C extends A

All the attributes and methods, if public, of class A will be inherited to Class C

Comment: Right, I understand, but where i'm asked to find out what kind of relationship this would be? Is there a special name at all? Or would it just be 'Class C extends A'

Comment: The key word is "Extending". The relationship is like functions (methods) added over a core/base object, without modifying the core, to get a "super" object.